# Defining an ad hoc proper noun

Tags: grammar, proper-nouns

Suppose I'm writing a report where I often refer to a particular training dataset and a particular control dataset.

Would it be grammatically correct to refer to them as to the Train dataset and the Control dataset, respectively?

Comment: "Training" and "Control" yes.  This is common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a useful convention in legal writing on creating specially defined nouns for the purpose of a single document or a single set of related documents.

"The data set numbered 123 and entitled "Training Dataset for Introductury Calculus, catalog number  M101-M102" (hereafter the "Training Dataset") ..." exemplifies a device that lets you exactly define a word or phrase outside its accepted meaning and still use the same word or phrase in its accepted sense by avoiding the initial capital letters.